# One redirection operator is not clear to me and that is <<

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

The usage of `<<` is not clear to me, can anyone explain this with a simple example? really appreciate that.

Comment: [Bash Reference Manual : 3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Comment: Or, open `man bash` on your computer and search on `<<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat <<'EOF'
hello $$
I'm a here document that doesn't interpolate
any $-variables because of the qutoes around
the EOF marker
EOF

echo -------

cat <<EOF
hello $$
I'm a here document that does interpolate
EOF

echo -------

cat <<x
It doesn't matter what you use as the end of file marker
x

echo -------

cat <<'x'
Quotes prevent $-interpolation
x
```

Output:

```
hello $$
I'm a here document that doesn't interpolate
any $-variables because of the qutoes around
the EOF marker
-------
hello 29843
I'm a here document that does interpolate
-------
It doesn't matter what you use as the end of file marker
-------
Quotes prevent $-interpolation
```